# Redirecting to a specific DIV on a page

Tags: javascript, html

have pages A And B in page A I have the link that takes you to page B but I want it to take you to a specific Div in that page B can please someone help
HTML

```
     <td><button type="button" class="btn bg-blue-grey" onclick="more()">More</button></td>
```

JS

```
function more() {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:62114/Occupant/wiz#step2";

}
```

Comment: It's called an anchor link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div on page B an ID, and then put that ID after a `#` in the link, eg:

```
<a href="page#my-div">
```

and

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

No need for Javascript